# Strange behavior ssh not working with different port but works with default

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, rhel, openssh

I am facing strange behaviour in my env. Everthing is working fine with port 22.

But when I change the port from 22 to anything else on the destination server redhat server is unble to connect it just hangs. But ubuntu server is able to connect the remote host from both the ports without any issue.

```
[admin@jumphost ~]$ ssh <remote_server_ip> -p 5252 -vvv
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host <remote_server_ip> originally <remote_server_ip>
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: not matched 'final'
debug2: match not found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-,gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname <remote_server_ip> is address
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host <remote_server_ip> originally <remote_server_ip>
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: matched 'final'
debug2: match found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-,gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to <remote_server_ip> <remote_server_ip> port 5252.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/admin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/admin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/admin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/admin/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/admin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/admin/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/admin/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/admin/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/admin/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0


remote server : ubuntu default port 22     

Source Server : Redhat using 22    
          : Ubuntu using 22
```

Comment: Does the redhat server have some outgoing firewall? Or is it behind a NAT/proxy?

Comment: firewalld disabled on all 3 server, Able to telnet to 5252.

Comment: Does it work if you disable SELinux temporarily (`setenforce Permissive`) on the server where the port is changed?

Comment: Selinux is disabled

Comment: Check /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny. Those files may not be dynamically updated if there's a change in the default port setting of the daemon.

Comment: Use "5252:<host>" instead if its a problem.

Comment: Tried everthing, seems the problem is with HW firewall